# Connecting to MS SQL database using ODBC drivers from local machine

Tags: sql-server, odbc, wamp

Currently we are using the odbc driver to connect to our MS SQL Server. We however want to be able to pull a directory down to our local machine, make changes, and push back to the server. We are able to connect to the MS SQL Server from our server but we cannot make the connection from our local machines. Does anyone know how to do this? We want to still use the odbc driver as that is what we are using on our server for connections.

thanks!

Comment: Sorry, you may need to have a look at the question again and decide if anybody that is not looking over your shoulder would understand exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not be able to connect to the Server via ODBC because of network issues. When you are creating your ODBC connection, have you tried to use the IP address of the SQL Server as opposed to the server name? You may also need to use the DOMAIN\Server syntax.

There are quite a number of potential reasons you cannot create the ODBC connection. This link addresses some of those issues:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b479cb4a-99a8-437a-8796-7d9f77910ec8/cant-create-an-odbc-connection?forum=sqlexpress

Hope this helps. Let me know if you still have issues.